# How to remove parts of a curve?

Tags: plotting, graphics, regions, output

I have a curve that have some unwanted parts.  How can I remove them ?  Or how to constraint the curve to a specific region ?

Here's a MWE that shows the problem :

```
t[tau_, v_, g_] := (Sinh[g tau + ArcTanh[v]] - Sinh[ArcTanh[v]])/g
x[tau_, v_, g_] := (Cosh[g tau + ArcTanh[v]] - Cosh[ArcTanh[v]])/g

Chi[t_, x_] := ArcTan[t + x] - ArcTan[t - x]
Eta[t_, x_] := ArcTan[t + x] + ArcTan[t - x]

curve[v_, g_] := ParametricPlot[
    {Chi[t[tau, v, g], x[tau, v, g]], Eta[t[tau, v, g], x[tau, v, g]]},
    {tau, -50, 50},
    PlotRange -> All
    ]

Show[curve[0.5, 2],
    PlotRange -> {{-Pi, Pi}, {-Pi, Pi}}, 
    Frame -> True]
```

Preview :

[image: curve]

The interesting part of that curve is inside the region delimited by a simple square losange, with corners at `{-Pi, 0}`, `{0, -Pi}`, `{Pi, 0}`and `{0, Pi}`.

So how can we draw the parts contained in that region only ?

Comment: Maybe do instead `{tau, -3, 3}`.

Comment: Use in your curve function {tau, -10, 9.5} instead of {tau, -50, 50}.

Comment: Well, this would be specific to the values used for `v`  and `g`, wouldn't ?  I need something more general, for all values of those parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
curve[v_, g_] := ParametricPlot[{Chi[t[tau, v, g], x[tau, v, g]], 
   Eta[t[tau, v, g], x[tau, v, g]]}, {tau, -50, 50}, PlotRange -> All,
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, u}, Norm[{x, y}, 1] < .99999 Pi]]

Show[RegionPlot[Norm[{x, y}, 1] <= Pi, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}], 
 curve[0.5, 2], PlotRange -> {{-Pi, Pi}, {-Pi, Pi}}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Show[RegionPlot[Norm[{x, y}, 1] <= Pi, {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}], 
 curve[.5, -4], PlotRange -> {{-Pi, Pi}, {-Pi, Pi}}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Wow !  That solution works very well.  Please, could you explain what the `Function[{x, y, u}, Norm[{x, y}, 1] < .99999 Pi]` is doing ?

Comment: @Cham, Your diamond  is the region where 1-norm is equal to `Pi`, i.e., the region where `Norm[{x,y},1] ==Pi`. So, the  specified `RegionFunction` is restricting the plotting region to `{x,y}` values with 1-norm less than `Pi`.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand.  What is a 1-norm ?  `Norm[{x, y}] = Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]`, isn't ?  Then what is `Norm[{x, y}, 1]` ?

Comment: Also, what is the `u` variable, in your `{x, y, u}` ?

Comment: Ok, `Norm[{x, y}, 1] = Abs[x] + Abs[y]` (that's new to me !).  But then what about that `u` variable ?

Comment: @Cham, `Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]` is the 2-Norm. 1-Norm is `Norm[{x, y}, 1] =Abs[x] + Abs[y]` (see [Norm>>Neat Examples](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Norm.html).) The `u` the `RegionFunction` arguments  corresponds to the `u` in `ParametricPlot[{fx, fy}, {u, umin, umax}]` , that is, it corresponds to `tau` in your `curve` function.

Comment: Thanks.  At the risk of sounding dumb, is there an advantage in writing `Norm[{x, y}, 1]` instead of `Abs[x] + Abs[y]` ?  The later seems to be simpler and clearer to me.

Comment: @Cham, I think it is a matter of taste. Based on my limited tests, `Norm` seems to be faster than `Abs[x] + Abs[y]` if one needs to use them on large lists; but in this case it should not be an issue.

Answer (score 6):

Using your definitions, let's derive a `RegionMemberFunction` that indicates whether a point lies on the boundary of the diamond-shaped region that you want to exclude from plotting:

```
rmf = RegionMember@DiscretizeRegion@Line[{{-Pi, 0}, {0, -Pi}, {Pi, 0}, {0, Pi}, {-Pi, 0}}];
```

Notice that the first point must be repeated to obtain a closed line.

Using that region membership function, we can define a new parametric plot including a `RegionFunction` directive that tests points to plot, and only plots them if they are *not* on part of that boundary:

```
Clear[curveLimited]
curveLimited[v_, g_] := 
 ParametricPlot[{Chi[t[tau, v, g], x[tau, v, g]], 
   Eta[t[tau, v, g], x[tau, v, g]]}, {tau, -50, 50}, PlotRange -> All,
   RegionFunction -> (Not[rmf[{#1, #2}]] &)
 ]

Show[
 curveLimited[.5, 2],
 PlotRange -> {{-Pi, Pi}, {-Pi, Pi}}, Frame -> True
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This works automatically **for any value of the plotting parameters**:

```
Show[
 curveLimited[.999, -3],
 PlotRange -> {{-Pi, Pi}, {-Pi, Pi}}, Frame -> True
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]